# PHP Mail() Function Sends an Email But Its not received in Inbox/Junk Folder

Tags: php, oracle, smtp

I am writing a simple PHP script that inserts a record in Oracle Database and upon successful insertion, sends an email to specified person. The values are being inserted successfully to the database, the mail is also sent, but not received in Inbox/Spam folder.

The code looks like this:

```
$query = "Some query";
$instmn = OCIParse ($conn,$query);
OciExecute ($instmn);
OCICommit;

if(oci_num_rows($instmn) == 1){

//

$rcvr = "example@eexample.com";
$msg = "Thankyou for using us!";
$sub = "Mail Recieved";


/*echo $rcvr;
echo $msg;
echo $sub;
//All values are displaying correctly
*/
$mail = mail($rcvr,$sub,$msg);
//echo $mail displays 1, means mail has been sent;

if($mail) 
{
echo "Thank you";

}

else

{
echo "Mail sending failed.";
}
```

Comment: please try var_dump($mail); ,that is show mail sent or not.

Comment: Assuming you are on a unix system, did you check you mail logs?

Comment: @fpietka I'm using windows

Comment: @apuravgaur did what you said. bool(true) returned..